# How to create a user interface using Swing in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I want to create a user interface (image below) in Java. I have used a grid layout, but how do I divide equally?

[image]

Comment: *Please give some code*. We are not a code writing service.

Comment: Try using GridBagLayout.. read about gridwidth and gridheight. Basically what I meant to say is you can divide the whole UI in 9 rows and 12 columns.. and just for you to understand, make the first grid i.e. x = 0, y = 0 (where I see time - 08:58:10) with gridwidth of 4.. and likewise

Comment: @Mady : give me reference link

Comment: Give me couple of minutes.. I'm writing a reference code for your help and better understanding.. meantime why don't you try reading about GridBagConstraints, gridwith and gridheight: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: That is an odd and quirky looking GUI.  I think it could be laid out better, and you should not try to emulate it.  Note: not one of the down voters, but they might be down voting because of so little sign of effort on your part, combined with 'Please give some code'. We might give code, we might not, but **most** object to being asked for code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your code

```
public class SwingSolution extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel componentPanel = null;   
    private JButton buttonWithWidth2 = null;    
    private JButton button2 = null; 
    private JButton buttonWithHeight2 = null;   
    private JButton button4 = null; 
    private JButton button5 = null;

    public JPanel getComponentPanel()
    {
       if(null == componentPanel)
       {
           componentPanel = new JPanel();
           GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
           componentPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout);

           GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();

           constraint.gridx = 0;
           constraint.gridy = 0;
           // Set gridwidth to 2 grids
           constraint.gridwidth = 2;
           buttonWithWidth2 = new JButton("Button Width 2");
           componentPanel.add(buttonWithWidth2, constraint);

           constraint.gridx = 2;
           constraint.gridy = 0;
           // set the gridwidth back to normal i.e. 1 grid
           constraint.gridwidth = 1;
           button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
           componentPanel.add(button2, constraint);

           constraint.gridx = 0;
           constraint.gridy = 1;
           // set the gridheight to 2
           constraint.gridheight = 2;
           buttonWithHeight2 = new JButton("Button Height 2");
           componentPanel.add(buttonWithHeight2, constraint);

           constraint.gridx = 1;
           constraint.gridy = 1;
           // set the gridheight back to normal i.e. 1 grid
           constraint.gridheight = 1;
           button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
           componentPanel.add(button4, constraint);

           constraint.gridx = 1;
           constraint.gridy = 2;
           button5 = new JButton("Button 5");
           componentPanel.add(button5, constraint);
       }

       return componentPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        SwingSolution main = new SwingSolution();

        frame.setTitle("Simple example");
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setContentPane(main.getComponentPanel());

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

It should give you output:

[image: Output]

[image: Output with grid marking]

Comment: thank in advance. now i understand GridBagLayout.